# Assembly - jumps to wrong function

Tags: assembly, flags

I have a code like this

```
MOV ax, a
MOV bl, x[si]
CBW
SUB ax, bx  
CMP ax, 0 
JE f2
JL f3
```

variables:

```
a DW 3
x DB -2
```

When the code works after sub ax should be 5, because `3-(-2) = 5 > 0`, but it jumps to function f3, when it should continue to work with f1 which starts right after this section of code. Any suggestions guys? also if x is 2 it works fine and code doesn't jump anywhere and function f1 works fine.

Comment: What is the value in `si`? I don't see it set, so I'm not sure how you are predicting your results.

Comment: si is just a index of array if we work only with -2 there is no need of that si :)

Comment: `CBW` only operates on `AX`, not `BX`. So you have who-knows-what in `BH` when you do `SUB AX,BX`. Even if `si` is fine (which I can't tell from the code sample), that will give you a problem. As an side, you don't need `CMP ax,0` since the previous `SUB` already sets the flag bits as a result of the subtraction.

Comment: So how I understand I don't need a CMP ax, 0 line in my code?

Comment: If you read the description of the `SUB` instruction online (just google "x86 sub instruction" it will tell you what flags are affected. And if you read the description of the `JE` instruction online, it will tell you under what flag conditions it jumps.

Comment: Of your old questions, would you consider accepting answers that helped you? To accept an answer, click the tick mark to the left of the question, until it turns green.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your *x* array holds signed bytes **and** you want to subtract these from the word in the AX register, you need to promote the signed byte to a signed word. We use the `MOVSX` instruction to do this.

Many assembly language instructions set the flags in accordance to the result of the operation. `SUB` is one of them and so you don't need to compare AX with 0 to be able to conditionally jump.

```
MOV   ax, a
MOVSX bx, x[si]
SUB   ax, bx
JE    f2
JL    f3
```